# Combining ranges adaptors and std::source_location got strange results

Tags: c++, c++20, std-ranges, std-source-location

Consider the [following useless code](https://godbolt.org/z/K6Wddq4do):

```
#include <ranges>
#include <source_location>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
  auto lines = std::views::iota(0, 5)
             | std::views::transform(
                [](int, const std::source_location& location = std::source_location::current()) 
                { return location.line(); }
               );
  for (const auto& line : lines)
    std::cout << line << "\n";
}
```

MSVC rejects with the strange error message:

```
(7): error C2676: binary '|': 'std::ranges::iota_view<_Ty1,_Ty2>' does not define this operator or a conversion to a type acceptable to the predefined operator
            with
            [
                _Ty1=int,
                _Ty2=int
            ]
```

And GCC outputs strange line number `61` no matter which row the `std::source_location::current()` is in:

```
61
61
61
61
61
```

Is the above code well-formed? If so, does it mean that both MSVC and GCC have bugs?

Comment: Can't tell you about MSVC, but I'm 99.9% sure default arguments are evaluated at the time of the function call, and for a closure object, that will be inside the code for the range function you are using, which would make line 61 kind of make sense.  Use `file_name` to confirm.

Comment: "*And GCC outputs strange line number 61 no matter which row the std::source_location::current() is in:*" Why is this surprising? Won't the function be called at the same place within the loop?

Comment: @NicolBolas. I mean, why not line `8`? How did this `61` come from?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

gcc is correct, the program is completely valid.

> And GCC outputs strange line number `61` no matter which row the `std::source_location::current()` is in:

That's because the default function argument, `current()`, is evaluated at the point of the function *call*, which has nothing to do with where the function is *declared*.

And this function is called by `transform_view`'s `iterator`'s `operator*()`. But not directly by `operator*()`, that operator is going to call `invoke` which itself is going to have to do a bunch of work to make sure it's invoked correctly. And the actual final overload in libstdc++'s implementation of `invoke` that gets called is... oh, look at that, it's [`bits/invoke.h:61`](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/817766f4dd2f6f3fdea2c4e6e22358b0b6b06d0d/libstdc%2B%2B-v3/include/bits/invoke.h#L61):

> ```cpp
> template<typename _Res, typename _Fn, typename... _Args>
>   constexpr _Res
>   __invoke_impl(__invoke_other, _Fn&& __f, _Args&&... __args)
>   { return std::forward<_Fn>(__f)(std::forward<_Args>(__args)...); }
> ```

---

This would've been easier to discover if instead of just printing the line number that `source_location` gives you, you also printed the file *name*:

```cpp
auto lines = std::views::iota(0, 5)
           | std::views::transform(
              [](int, const std::source_location& location = std::source_location::current()) 
              { return fmt::format("{}:{}", location.file_name(), location.line()); }
             );

fmt::print("{}\n", lines);
```

Which prints a range containing the string `/opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-trunk-20210817/include/c++/12.0.0/bits/invoke.h:61`, five times.

Comment: The source file was unintentionally exposed, which sounds good.

Comment: gcc trunk crashes if you switch source_location to auto :)  https://godbolt.org/z/MxM8se3f6

Comment: @NoSenseEtAl. [Reduced](https://godbolt.org/z/nqzh88j1e). Have you reported the bug?

Comment: @康桓瑋 no, I am not registered at gcc bugzilla.

Comment: @NoSenseEtAl. [PR102005](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=102005)

Comment: @康桓瑋 thank you for submitting it, but it looks like it is a 1y old unfixed bug :/